# Running two process in C++ and wait for them to finish

Tags: c++, multithreading

My C++ is pretty basic and this is my first time attempting a multithread code. 
So my datasets as being quite large I am thinking I can cut time by separating some of the functions. Depicted below in Pseudocode is a general idea of what I want.

```
int main(){

    process1();
    process2();

}

process1(){
    base value for recursion
    Builds a forward array
    Once complete - run function combination();
    Recursive call 
}

process2(){
    base value for recursion
    Builds backwards array
    Once complete - run function combination();
    Recursive call
}

combination(){
    when both functions are complete.
    if functions return null then the array is complete
    else add results into a new array.
}
```

The recursive call is what could be my conundrum here. Is there a simple way to implement where the two process must complete their first iteration to run combination and then goes through it again?

Comment: Oh this code wants SIMD so hard....

Answer (score 4):

This is not running two [*processes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) but running two *threads*.

A process has, almost by definition, its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). So two different processes cannot share memory without specific steps (on Linux, see [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)). A process can have several threads which all share the same virtual address space, each thread having its own [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) in that virtual address space.

This [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) teaches interesting concepts about P-threads (which you can easily adapt to [C++11 threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread))

You probably want to learn more about [condition variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) and [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) since you should care about [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)).

Comment: Yep I'm reading through right now, a lot more complicated than I thought it out to be. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a simple way to implement where the two process must complete their first iteration to run combination and then goes through it again?

A signal.  You want a thread to wait on a signal.  Also called [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). ([Posix](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview))

There are lots of resources on multithreading and its a technique that you **should definitely learn** (with multicores being standard these days).

[Strategized Locking, Thread-safe Interface, and scoped Locking](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/locking-patterns.pdf).

[Half-Sync/Half-ASync](http://www1.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/PLoP-95.pdf) (describing concurrent queues)

[Atomicity Policies using Design Patterns](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2666/b773dd9e1f42619ede856a9b45d5689bec47.pdf) (describes producers/consumers, read/write policies).